# How to use order by in spring jpa when the query is to find by keyword

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a query which looks like this,

```
@Query("select p from Product p where p.title like concat ('%',?1,'%') and p.categoryId = ?2")
```

How do I use the order by?
I tried following it gave me syntax exception

```
@Query("select p from Product p where p.title like concat ('%',?1,'%') and p.categoryId = ?2" order by createddate desc)
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If **createddate** is a Product field, try:

```
@Query("select p from Product p where p.title like concat ('%',?1,'%') and p.categoryId = ?2 order by p.createddate desc")
```

Comment: please move the **"** to the end of the query

Answer (score 0):

show the exception.IMO, you have the wrong spelling.